# Subversion (1.8.13) installation without root

Tags: svn, compile

I wanted to install a newer version of svn without root access. On ubuntu, the apt-get version is:

`svn --version`

> svn, version 1.8.8 (r1568071)

While I would like to install the more recent one `subversion-1.8.13`.

The server I am doing this hasn't the apr, apr-util installed, for this, I've also installed them on standalone:

```
cd $HOME
mkdir custom_installed
cd custom_installed
# Install apr
wget ftp://mirror.switch.ch/mirror/apache/dist//apr/apr-1.5.2.tar.gz
tar xvfz apr-1.5.2.tar.gz
cd apr-1.5.2
./configure —prefix=$HOME/custom_installed
make
make test
make install
cd ..

# Install apu
wget ftp://mirror.switch.ch/mirror/apache/dist//apr/apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz
tar xvfz apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz
cd apr-util-1.5.4
./configure --prefix=$HOME/custom_installed --with-apr=$HOME/custom_installed
make
make test
make install
cd ..
```

It seems to be correctly installed on the custom_installed, it has the following include, lib and bin archives:

`ls lib`

> apr.exp     aprutil.exp  libapr-1.la  libapr-1.so.0
>   libaprutil-1.a   libaprutil-1.so    libaprutil-1.so.0.5.4 apr-util-1 
>   libapr-1.a   libapr-1.so  libapr-1.so.0.5.2  libaprutil-1.la 
>   libaprutil-1.so.0  pkgconfig

`ls include/apr-1`

> apr_allocator.h  apr_dbm.h        apr_general.h       apr_ldap_init.h 
>   apr_mmap.h            apr_queue.h    apr_signal.h
>   apr_thread_pool.h    apr_want.h apr_anylock.h    apr_dso.h
>   apr_getopt.h        apr_ldap_option.h  apr_network_io.h
>   apr_random.h   apr_skiplist.h      apr_thread_proc.h    apr_xlate.h
>   apr_atomic.h     apr_env.h        apr_global_mutex.h 
>   apr_ldap_rebind.h  apr_optional.h        apr_reslist.h  apr_strings.h 
>   apr_thread_rwlock.h  apr_xml.h apr_base64.h     apr_errno.h      apr.h
>   apr_ldap_url.h     apr_optional_hooks.h  apr_ring.h     apr_strmatch.h
>   apr_time.h           apu_errno.h apr_buckets.h    apr_escape.h
>   apr_hash.h          apr_lib.h          apr_poll.h            apr_rmm.h
>   apr_support.h       apr_uri.h            apu.h apr_crypto.h
>   apr_file_info.h  apr_hooks.h         apr_md4.h          apr_pools.h
>   apr_sdbm.h     apr_tables.h        apr_user.h           apu_version.h
>   apr_date.h       apr_file_io.h    apr_inherit.h       apr_md5.h
>   apr_portable.h        apr_sha1.h     apr_thread_cond.h   apr_uuid.h
>   apu_want.h apr_dbd.h        apr_fnmatch.h    apr_ldap.h
>   apr_memcache.h     apr_proc_mutex.h      apr_shm.h
>   apr_thread_mutex.h  apr_version.h

`ls bin`

> apr-1-config  apu-1-config

However, when I am trying to install the svn, either using the tarball:

```
wget http://apache.claz.org/subversion/subversion-1.8.13.tar.gz
tar xvfz subversion-1.8.13.tar.gz
cd subversion-1.8.13
wget http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3071501.zip
unzip sqlite-amalgamation-3071501.zip
mv sqlite-amalgamation-3071501 sqlite-amalgamation
./configure --prefix=$HOME/custom_installed --with-apr=$HOME/custom_installed --with-apr-util=$HOME/custom_installed
make
```

or the svn trunk:

```
svn co https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk svn
cd svn
# get SQLite amalgamation if required
chmod +x autogen.sh
./autogen.sh
wget http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3071501.zip
unzip sqlite-amalgamation-3071501.zip
mv sqlite-amalgamation-3071501 sqlite-amalgamation
./configure —prefix=$HOME/custom_installed --with-apr=$HOME/custom_installed --with-apr-util=$HOME/custom_installed
make
```

I keep getting this error:

> libtool: link: warning: library
>   `/home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib/libapr-1.la' was moved. /bin/sed:
>   can't read /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la: No such file or directory
>   libtool: link:`/usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la' is not a valid libtool
>   archive make: *** [subversion/libsvn_subr/libsvn_subr-1.la] Error 1

during the linkage:

```
cd subversion/libsvn_subr && /bin/bash "/home/wsfreund/custom_installed/svn/libtool" --tag=CC --silent --mode=link gcc  -g -O2  -g -O2 -pthread    -rpath /home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib -version-info 0 -Wl,--no-undefined -o libsvn_subr-1.la  adler32.lo atomic.lo auth.lo base64.lo bit_array.lo cache-inprocess.lo cache-membuffer.lo cache-memcache.lo cache.lo cache_config.lo checksum.lo cmdline.lo compat.lo compress.lo config.lo config_auth.lo config_file.lo config_win.lo crypto.lo ctype.lo date.lo debug.lo deprecated.lo dirent_uri.lo dso.lo eol.lo error.lo fnv1a.lo gpg_agent.lo hash.lo io.lo iter.lo lock.lo log.lo macos_keychain.lo magic.lo md5.lo mergeinfo.lo mutex.lo nls.lo object_pool.lo opt.lo packed_data.lo path.lo pool.lo prefix_string.lo prompt.lo properties.lo quoprint.lo root_pools.lo simple_providers.lo skel.lo sorts.lo spillbuf.lo sqlite.lo sqlite3wrapper.lo ssl_client_cert_providers.lo ssl_client_cert_pw_providers.lo ssl_server_trust_providers.lo stream.lo string.lo subst.lo sysinfo.lo target.lo temp_serializer.lo time.lo token.lo types.lo user.lo username_providers.lo utf.lo utf8proc.lo utf_validate.lo utf_width.lo validate.lo version.lo win32_crashrpt.lo win32_crypto.lo win32_xlate.lo x509info.lo x509parse.lo xml.lo -L/home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib -laprutil-1 -L/home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib -lapr-1 -lexpat -lz  -ldl -lpthread
```

What is most strange, I don't have a clue **why** it wants to find it on `/usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la`, since it should find it on `/home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib`…

Adding more info:

```
/home/wsfreund/custom_installed/svn/libtool --tag=CC --mode=link gcc  -g -O2  -g -O2 -pthread    -rpath /home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib -version-info 0 -Wl,--no-undefined -o libsvn_subr-1.la  adler32.lo atomic.lo auth.lo base64.lo bit_array.lo cache-inprocess.lo cache-membuffer.lo cache-memcache.lo cache.lo cache_config.lo checksum.lo cmdline.lo compat.lo compress.lo config.lo config_auth.lo config_file.lo config_win.lo crypto.lo ctype.lo date.lo debug.lo deprecated.lo dirent_uri.lo dso.lo eol.lo error.lo fnv1a.lo gpg_agent.lo hash.lo io.lo iter.lo lock.lo log.lo macos_keychain.lo magic.lo md5.lo mergeinfo.lo mutex.lo nls.lo object_pool.lo opt.lo packed_data.lo path.lo pool.lo prefix_string.lo prompt.lo properties.lo quoprint.lo root_pools.lo simple_providers.lo skel.lo sorts.lo spillbuf.lo sqlite.lo sqlite3wrapper.lo ssl_client_cert_providers.lo ssl_client_cert_pw_providers.lo ssl_server_trust_providers.lo stream.lo string.lo subst.lo sysinfo.lo target.lo temp_serializer.lo time.lo token.lo types.lo user.lo username_providers.lo utf.lo utf8proc.lo utf_validate.lo utf_width.lo validate.lo version.lo win32_crashrpt.lo win32_crypto.lo win32_xlate.lo x509info.lo x509parse.lo xml.lo -L/home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib -laprutil-1 -L/home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib -lapr-1 -lexpat -lz  -ldl -lpthread --debug --config
```

> libtool: link: warning: library `/home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib/libapr-1.la' was moved.

```
libtool: link: rm -fr  .libs/libsvn_subr-1.a .libs/libsvn_subr-1.so .libs/libsvn_subr-1.so.0 .libs/libsvn_subr-1.so.0.0.0

libtool: link: gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/adler32.o .libs/atomic.o .libs/auth.o .libs/base64.o .libs/bit_array.o .libs/cache-inprocess.o .libs/cache-membuffer.o .libs/cache-memcache.o .libs/cache.o .libs/cache_config.o .libs/checksum.o .libs/cmdline.o .libs/compat.o .libs/compress.o .libs/config.o .libs/config_auth.o .libs/config_file.o .libs/config_win.o .libs/crypto.o .libs/ctype.o .libs/date.o .libs/debug.o .libs/deprecated.o .libs/dirent_uri.o .libs/dso.o .libs/eol.o .libs/error.o .libs/fnv1a.o .libs/gpg_agent.o .libs/hash.o .libs/io.o .libs/iter.o .libs/lock.o .libs/log.o .libs/macos_keychain.o .libs/magic.o .libs/md5.o .libs/mergeinfo.o .libs/mutex.o .libs/nls.o .libs/object_pool.o .libs/opt.o .libs/packed_data.o .libs/path.o .libs/pool.o .libs/prefix_string.o .libs/prompt.o .libs/properties.o .libs/quoprint.o .libs/root_pools.o .libs/simple_providers.o .libs/skel.o .libs/sorts.o .libs/spillbuf.o .libs/sqlite.o .libs/sqlite3wrapper.o .libs/ssl_client_cert_providers.o .libs/ssl_client_cert_pw_providers.o .libs/ssl_server_trust_providers.o .libs/stream.o .libs/string.o .libs/subst.o .libs/sysinfo.o .libs/target.o .libs/temp_serializer.o .libs/time.o .libs/token.o .libs/types.o .libs/user.o .libs/username_providers.o .libs/utf.o .libs/utf8proc.o .libs/utf_validate.o .libs/utf_width.o .libs/validate.o .libs/version.o .libs/win32_crashrpt.o .libs/win32_crypto.o .libs/win32_xlate.o .libs/x509info.o .libs/x509parse.o .libs/xml.o   -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib -L/home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib /home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib/libaprutil-1.so /home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib/libapr-1.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so -lz -ldl -lpthread  -O2 -O2 -pthread -Wl,--no-undefined   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libsvn_subr-1.so.0 -o .libs/libsvn_subr-1.so.0.0.0

libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libsvn_subr-1.so.0" && ln -s "libsvn_subr-1.so.0.0.0" "libsvn_subr-1.so.0")

libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libsvn_subr-1.so" && ln -s "libsvn_subr-1.so.0.0.0" "libsvn_subr-1.so")

libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libsvn_subr-1.a  adler32.o atomic.o auth.o base64.o bit_array.o cache-inprocess.o cache-membuffer.o cache-memcache.o cache.o cache_config.o checksum.o cmdline.o compat.o compress.o config.o config_auth.o config_file.o config_win.o crypto.o ctype.o date.o debug.o deprecated.o dirent_uri.o dso.o eol.o error.o fnv1a.o gpg_agent.o hash.o io.o iter.o lock.o log.o macos_keychain.o magic.o md5.o mergeinfo.o mutex.o nls.o object_pool.o opt.o packed_data.o path.o pool.o prefix_string.o prompt.o properties.o quoprint.o root_pools.o simple_providers.o skel.o sorts.o spillbuf.o sqlite.o sqlite3wrapper.o ssl_client_cert_providers.o ssl_client_cert_pw_providers.o ssl_server_trust_providers.o stream.o string.o subst.o sysinfo.o target.o temp_serializer.o time.o token.o types.o user.o username_providers.o utf.o utf8proc.o utf_validate.o utf_width.o validate.o version.o win32_crashrpt.o win32_crypto.o win32_xlate.o x509info.o x509parse.o xml.o
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libsvn_subr-1.a
```

> /bin/sed: can't read /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la: No such file or
>   directory libtool: link: `/usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la' is not a
>   valid libtool archive

This was also reported to `users@subversion.apache.org`

Comment: Did you check the contents of the `libapr-1.la` file itself?  See [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838621/libtool-think-that-a-library-was-moved-but-it-isnt-the-case) for details on why it might say the library was moved.  You might also want to try following the steps in [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835108/specify-non-default-shared-library-path-in-gcc-linux) - specifically, add your local compiled library path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or modify the `Makefile` to set the `-rpath` flag for any calls to `gcc` while linking.

Comment: It seems that you were right. The `libapr-1.la` had wrong path. I've corrected it, checking if it works now after re-running `/configure`. Thank you!

Comment: @Breakthrough I've made it. It was needed to change manually both files (`libapr-1.la`:`libdir='/home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib'`;`libaprutil-1.la`,`dependency_libs update path to /home/wsfreund/custom_installed/lib/libapr-1.la`). You could write this as an answer and I will be glad to accept it x)

Comment: I've added an answer below with some additional details from my above comment, but feel free to edit it and add any other information you feel is relevant or missing.  Glad you got the issue sorted out, thank you for following up with a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838621/libtool-think-that-a-library-was-moved-but-it-isnt-the-case), both of the `.la` files (`libapr-1.la` and `libaprutil-1.la`) files describe the libraries themselves, and should be commented.  It's likely that the paths referenced in these files are incorrect or defaulting to your system's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Editing both files with a text editor, and updating the respective paths to point to your newly compiled library binaries should resolve the issue.  Specifics regarding the changes to make are detailed below.

---

If the issue still persists, a further [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835108/specify-non-default-shared-library-path-in-gcc-linux) might be of help.  You can manually add your locally compiled libraries to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` temporarily, or set the `-rpath` flag for any `gcc` calls by editing the `Makefile` (or any build scripts), to override the default shared library paths.

---

---

Editing both files with a text editor, and updating the respective paths to point to your newly compiled library binaries should resolve the issue. In this specific case, it was needed to change the following files:

line `41` on file `libapr-1.la`:

```
libdir='/usr/local/apr/lib' # change to your installation path
```

and line `20` on `libaprutil-1.la`:

```
dependency_libs=' /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.la /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl' # change libapr-1.la path to the correct one
```

After, make sure to reset installation configuration files by doing (adapt the ./configure to your correct paths and needs):

```
make clean
./configure —prefix=$HOME/custom_installed --with-apr=$HOME/custom_installed/bin/apr-1-config --with-apr-util=$HOME/custom_installed/bin/apu-1-config
```